# bootstrap PowerMock with @Rule ,but failed

Tags: junit, mocking, powermock

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ SessionUtil.class})
public class FundControllerTest {
     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.......
}
```

Run Junit as above, it works well.

But when I try to run Junit as below, it failed. Because I need use Eclemma to

coverage my test, so I switch to use @Rule to bootstrap PowerMock, but failed. Please help.

```
@PrepareForTest({ SessionUtil.class})
public class FundControllerTest {
    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();
    /*
    static{
        PowerMockAgent.initializeIfNeeded();
    }
    */
   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX..........
}
```

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to enqueue operation: the target VM does not support attach mechanism
    at org.powermock.modules.agent.AgentLoader.getVirtualMachineImplementationFromEmbeddedOnes(AgentLoader.java:122)
    at org.powermock.modules.agent.AgentLoader.loadAgent(AgentLoader.java:81)
    at org.powermock.modules.agent.AgentInitialization.initializeAccordingToJDKVersion(AgentInitialization.java:40)
    at org.powermock.modules.agent.PowerMockAgent.initializeIfNeeded(PowerMockAgent.java:91)
    at com.hsbc.mf.frtend.twfunds.controller.FundControllerTest.<clinit>(FundControllerTest.java:53)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:527)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to enqueue operation: the target VM does not support attach mechanism
    at sun.tools.attach.WindowsVirtualMachine.<init>(WindowsVirtualMachine.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:527)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.createInstance(WhiteboxImpl.java:1455)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeConstructor(WhiteboxImpl.java:1303)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeConstructor(Whitebox.java:497)
    at org.powermock.modules.agent.AgentLoader.getVirtualMachineImplementationFromEmbeddedOnes(AgentLoader.java:120)
    ... 28 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you find a snake in your bed, does it matter whether it crawled through the open window; or came through the front door?

In other words: in order to allow for mocking **static** code; PowerMock needs to manipulate the byte code of that **production** class SessionUtils. And EclEmma also relies on byte code manipulation.

Perhaps, at some future point, the implementations of both frameworks will work together (but the corresponding [bug](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/422) is almost two years old; and there isn't much activity around it; so don't hold your breath on it).

But today, PowerMock and EclEmma do not work together. End of story.

And it doesn't matter to "pull in" PowerMock using its own runner; or using the "rule approach". Because as said: the problem is that you found that snake in your bed; and not "how did it get there".

Now you simply have to decide what is more important to you: to keep your production code as is (and its design, that forces you to mock static calls with PowerMock); or to acquire coverage information.

My personal two cents: that is one of the reasons why my team gave up on PowerMock completely. Instead, we focus on writing code that is testable without mocking static/new calls; and guess what: that works fine. And our production code is **better** than before.